# Options with color package clash with acmart documentclass?

Tags: color, packages, package-options, acmart

I'm trying to use a package that imports `color` with the `dvipsnames,usenames` options. Unfortunately, my document uses the ACM format, which appears to already import the `color` package with no options.

The following file:

```
\documentclass[acmlarge,dvipsnames,usenames]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}

% Document starts
\begin{document}
% Title portion
\title{A Multifrequency MAC Specially Designed for Wireless Sensor
  Network Applications}
\titlenote{We can add a note to the title}

\maketitle
Body
\end{document}
```

Gives the following, highly unhelpful error error:

```
   LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.
```

Is this a known problem? Is there an easy workaround for importing packages that conflict in their options?

Comment: just remove the usepackage{color} line, the color package will see the options on `\documentclass`

Comment: Pressing `h` at the error prompt gets a more helpful text including the offending options.

Comment: Probably the class loads package `xcolor` instead of `color`.

Comment: Option `usenames` is obsolete: it's now the default.